# Postges: Server closed the connection unexpectedly on delete query

Tags: postgresql

When i execute `DELETE FROM "table" WHERE id = 1`, i get *"Server closed the connection unexpectedly"* or *"FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode"* (sometimes the first, sometimes the second).

This problem started after i added the "deleted_at" column with "default NULL" to the table.

I was able to fix this bug by execute `UPDATE "table" SET deleted_at = NULL WHERE deleted_at IS NULL`

After that, `DELETE FROM "table" WHERE id = 1` is executed successfully.

But i don't understand, why it works like this?

I am using PostgreSQL 11.0. 
Columns added by Yii2 migrations, if important.

Comment: Please examine the PostgreSQL log file and add the relevant lines to the question.

Comment: The current version of the 11 series is 11.6.  Maybe you have run into a bug which was already fixed over a year ago.

Comment: Yes, updating to 11.6 solved the problem. I think this is an old Postgres bug.